# llenado de formulario PHP y envió de correo automático

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Realizo un modulo en php donde se levanta un ticket de trabajo, lo que quiero que haga es que al llenar y enviar el formulario envié automáticamente un correo con los datos que lleno el usuario de confirmación espero en verdad me puedan orientar. Anexo mi código.

Saludos

```html
<?php
    $priorities =mysqli_query($con, "select * from priority");
    $turns =mysqli_query($con, "select * from turn");
    $areas =mysqli_query($con, "select * from area");
    $statuses =mysqli_query($con, "select * from status");
    $kinds =mysqli_query($con, "select * from kind");
    $categories =mysqli_query($con, "select * from category");
 
?>

    <div> <!-- Modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar Ticket</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Tickets</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="post" id="add" name="add">
                        <div id="result"></div>
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Tipo
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="kind_id" >
                                      <?php foreach($kinds as $p):?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Titulo<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Descripción <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <textarea name="description" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Seguimiento de Proceso
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <textarea name="process_1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="Seguimiento de Proceso"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Fin de Proceso
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <textarea name="process_2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="Fin de Proceso"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Area
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="area_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                      <?php foreach($areas as $p):?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
                       
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Categoria
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="category_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                      <?php foreach($categories as $p):?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Prioridad</span>
       </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="priority_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                  <?php foreach($priorities as $p):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Turno<span class="required">*</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="turn_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                  <?php foreach($turns as $p):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Estado
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="status_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                  <?php foreach($statuses as $p):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                              <button id="save_data" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

      
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /Modal -->
```

Comment: Te falta agregar en la etiqueta "form", la propiedad "action" con el nombre del archivo donde está el script para procesar los datos y enviarlos con la función mail() de PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar un correo automático puedes hacer uso de la función "mail()" de php

Puedes consultar la documentación de la función aquí:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Para hacer uso de la función te dejo un código de muestra que puedes utilizar para enviar correos desde PHP, lo único que tendrías que definir es si enviar los datos capturados a otro PHP donde puedas procesarlos, es decir, a donde envias el formulario para guardarlo ahi podrías usar el siguiente código.

```
$to = "mimail@mimail.com";

$subject = "Este es el ASUNTO del correo.";

$htmlContent = ''; //Aquí puedes crear el template que se usará para enviar el correo concatenando las variables de los datos. Recomiendo usar TABLE para esquematizar más fácil el contenido.

            // Aquí estableces los headers del correo, por lo general estos son iguales siempre para cualquier correo.
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            // Este header es importante, ya que es el 'nombre' que se muestra al lado del correo cuando llega.
            $headers .= 'From: NOMBRE DEL SISTEMA<hello@sistema.com>' . "\r\n";

            // Enviar el correo, agregando las variables anteriormente definidas.
            if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)):
                $successMsg = 'Email has sent successfully.';
            else:
                $errorMsg = 'Email sending fail.';
            endif;
```

Espero te sirva al menos para darte una idea, quedo pendiente :)